# How do you select a single array item from a data object and pass it to another component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have some data that I get from axios and pass to a Bootstrap table. In my computed properties where I declare the nameOfPerson field, I have made a click event, so that when a user clicks on the name, a modal opens. This modal also contains the data shown in the table.

However, I would like to change it so that when you click on the name of a person, ONLY the data for THAT single person gets passed to the modal. So instead of passing a prop containing data of ALL users the modal, I just want the data related to the name that I actually click on.

How would I accomplish this?

The parent:

```
<template>
 <b-container>
  <b-card class="mt-4">
  <b-table
    :items="dataItems"
    :fields="fields"
    :per-page="[5, 10]"
    sort-desc
    primary-key="id"
  />
</b-card>
<data-modal ref="dataModal" :selected-name="dataItems"/>
</b-container>
</template>

<script>
  import {axiosComponent} from '@/axios/services';
  import DataModal from '@/components/DataModal';

  export default {
    components: {
      DataModal
    },

    data() {
      return {
        dataItems: null,
      };
    },
    computed: {
      fields() {
        return [
          {
            key: 'nameOfperson',
            label: 'name',
            sortable: true
            click: () => this.$refs.dataModal.show(),
          },
          {
            key: 'ageOfPerson',
            label: 'Age',
            sortable: true
          },
        ]
      },
    },
    methods: {
      load(){
        axiosComponent.getData().then(result => {
          this.dataItems = result.data
        })
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.load()
    }
  };
</script>
```

The child (modal)

```
  <template>
  <b-modal v-model="showModal">
    <div v-for="log in selectedName">
      {{ log }}
    </div>
  </b-modal>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
    props: {
      selectedName: Array
    },
    data() {
      return {
        showModal: false,
      };
    },
    methods: {
      show(){
        this.showModal = true
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Your table can [emit](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#emitting-and-listening-to-events) a message when the selected user has changed (along with its index in `dataItems` or the whole object if you want). The parent can then open the model with that data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@row-selected` method, take a look at following demo:

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: `
    <b-modal v-model="showModal">
      <div v-for="log in selectedName">
        {{ log }}
      </div>
    </b-modal>
  `,
  props: {
    selectedName: Array,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showModal: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    show(){
      this.showModal = true
    }
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      dataItems: null,
      selected: null,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    fields() {
      return [
        {
          key: 'nameOfperson',
          label: 'name',
          sortable: true,
        },
        {
          key: 'ageOfPerson',
          label: 'Age',
          sortable: true
        },
      ]
    },
  },
  methods: {
    load(){
     // axiosComponent.getData().then(result => {
        this.dataItems = [{id: 1, nameOfperson: 'aaa', ageOfPerson: 5}, {id: 2, nameOfperson: 'bbb', ageOfPerson: 25}, {id: 3, nameOfperson: 'ccc', ageOfPerson: 35}, {id: 4, nameOfperson: 'ddd', ageOfPerson: 45}]
     // })
    },
    onRowSelected(items) {
      this.selected = items
      this.$refs.dataModal.show()
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.load()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <b-container>
    <b-card class="mt-4">
    <b-table
      :items="dataItems"
      :fields="fields"
      :per-page="5"
      sort-desc
      primary-key="id"
      selectable
      :select-mode="'single'"
      @row-selected="onRowSelected"
    />
    </b-card>
    <child ref="dataModal" :selected-name="selected"></child>
  </b-container>
</div>
```